# Quering SqlLite database where clause Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

Hi I am developing an android app.I am trying to query from the database. I need to fetch everything from the table TASK where dbDate = AlarmDate and dbdTime = AlarmTime.

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TASK WHERE dbDate = '"+AlarmDate+"' AND dbTime= '"+Alarmtime+"'", null);
```

The problem is ,the cursor c is null. 
I am not sure where I am going wrong in the query. Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you store dbDate and dbTime? And what is in variables AlarmDate and Alarmtime?

Comment: dbDate and dbTime are fields in table TASK which holds String type values. AlarmDate and Alarmtime are String values

Answer (score 0):

Android has binding method to avoid sql inject. You can use the second parameter to provide the variables of SQL.

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TASK WHERE dbDate = ? AND dbTime = ? ", new String[]{AlarmDate, AlarmDate});
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment 'I have used `db = openOrCreateDatabase("Globus", 0, null);` where Globus is the db name', you are not using SQLite properly with android.

What you should be doing is creating class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, then make sure you override the `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods, these are the methods where you create tables and make changes, it has been said a hundred times on here so I will provide a link to a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

When you do database operations, on the class call `getWritableDatabase` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase())

I say call `getWritableDatabase` because that way you don't need to worry if you can write to it, a writable database is also readable. Just FYI. Ask away for more details.

This should be the process of reading (writing is the same, just use what method you want instead of `query`):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();//this should lock the tables you are reading
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select 1 where 1=?", new String[]{"1"});
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        //Do what you want with the row
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

Here is the source code of a database helper I wrote, maybe it will help, read through it, understand how it works. https://bitbucket.org/FabianCCook/dbhelper/src/af7a8eba8d1a3f139e4170bbef9f1a2d3fdf1b47/src/nz/smartlemon/DatabaseHelper/ApplicationDataDbHelper.java?at=master

And if you want to know the reason the `open` methods exist read through this code

(This class was made from the help of someone elses code)

https://bitbucket.org/FabianCCook/dbhelper/src/af7a8eba8d1a3f139e4170bbef9f1a2d3fdf1b47/src/nz/smartlemon/DatabaseHelper/SDCardSQLiteOpenHelper.java?at=master

Answer (score -1):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();


 Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TASK WHERE dbDate = '"+AlarmDate+"' AND dbTime = '"+AlarmTime+"'",new String [] {});
```

Make sure you have gotten a readable database for 'db' or it will return null everytime.
Also change the end of your raw query to new String [] {}

Hope this helps, this is what I use in my applications.

Comment: I have used db = openOrCreateDatabase("Globus", 0, null); where Globus is the db name.

Comment: An empty parameter list is superfluous.